# Unable to start the int correctly and keep the number back from the function

Tags: c, function, struct

First at all sorry for my english, i will try my best.

Well, here's the problem, I am making a C program just for learning, the program is basically a students manager, I wanted to add a final function in which the user would be prompted by an id to by remove and after inserting that id the student would be eliminate from the database, the problem is... when the data is inserted in the first case there's added a subroutine that automatically adds the id as and int in the struct,problem is it shows a random int number like "43405" or so I thought to start the integer to 1, the problem is when the function is re-called again id will back to be 1 and that just simply don't work.

P.D:I read some of you guys told me about to make the code more readable, can you give me a nice "tutorial" or so to make that?

Function:

```
int insertar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20], int n,int id_alumno){


    char resp[3];

    system("cls");
    puts("\n \a Insercion del alumno\n"); 
    while (!strstr(resp,"no")){
          fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEl ID de este alumno sera: %d\n", id_alumno);
            notas[n].id=id_alumno;
            id_alumno++;
            puts("\nDime el nombre del Alumno\n");
            scanf("%10s", notas[n].alumno );
            system("cls");
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("\nDime el apellido del Alumno\n");
            scanf("%10s", notas[n].apellido );
            system("cls");
            puts("\nDime la Primera nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
            scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota1 );
            system("cls");
            puts("\nDime la Segunda nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
            scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota2 );
            system("cls");
            puts("\nDime la Tercera nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
            scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota3 );
            n++;
            system("cls");
            puts("\nQuieres volver a insertar otro?[si|no]\n");
            scanf("%3s", resp);
            strlwr(resp);

    }

    return n;

    return id_alumno;




}
```

Main for more info:

```
int main (void){

int menu = 0, n = 0, id_alumno;    
struct alumnos notas[20];


puts("\n<><><>Bienvenido al recuento de notas de la escuela<><><>\n"); 
puts("\nQue deseas hacer?\n"); 


while (menu != 5){

      puts("\n1)Insertas las notas de un alumno\n2)Ver todas las notas\n3)Ver las notas de un alumno\n4)Modificar notas\n5)Salir\n"); 
       scanf("%d", &menu);
         switch(menu){

                   case 1:

                        n=insertar_notas(notas,n,id_alumno);
                        break;
```

Comment: Note on readability. If you can demonstrate your problem in fewer lines of code (while making sure the example is still complete in reproducibility), that is always more readable.

Comment: Ok, lets see if this is better.

Comment: Never use `fflush(stdin)` - it may result in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Problem is inside the function theres a while, so you can add new students unlimited , so i want that id unique.

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass by value, so to make id_alumno modifiable you need to pass it as a pointer:

```
int insertar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20], int n,int *id_alumno) { // id_alumno is now a pointer to int inside this function


    char resp[3];

    system("cls");
    puts("\n \a Insercion del alumno\n"); 
    while (!strstr(resp,"no")){
          fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEl ID de este alumno sera: %d\n", *id_alumno);  // Use * to access the value
            notas[n].id=id_alumno;
            (*id_alumno)++;  // Use * to access the value. ++ has higher precedence than *, so need parenthesis around *id_alumno
           ...
```

And in the call from main:

```
                    n=insertar_notas(notas, n, &id_alumno);  // address-of id_alumno
```

Also, you need to initialize id_alumno in main:

```
int menu = 0, n = 0, id_alumno = 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is if i call back that function the new user will have again the same id as another user.

Comment: The solution is to make the variable `static`. static variables keep their value between calls.

Comment: Cant make it works...i dont know im trying to keep the value in  pointers but i have problems of arguments and it seems i can fix the pointer to "1".

Comment: Just changed the code and its works! thanks so i undertand i only can return 1 x function, and the pointer makes a direction in the memory, thanks!

Comment: Yes, there can be only one return value from a function in C. If you need more output variables you can do it like in my answer, using pointers.